# Ideal way of creating a custom data structure, given my use case

Tags: java, class, variables, runtime

This is again, I guess, a 'best practices' question because i can think of some inelegant ways of getting my use case implemented. 
My use case is as follows 
Im writing a MethodManager(sort of) module which helps in the end user dealing with actual method(function) calls through a UI. 
For this specific purpose i have a methodDefinition class which is an object form of what a method(function) looks like to my system.
A brief overview of what my methodDefinition's members look like is as follows

```
methodName -- String
methodInputs -- ArrayList<String>
methodResultType -- enum(STRING,MAP,LIST)
methodResult  -- <<variable, on the basis of methodResultType>>
```

Now methodResult is variable and can be any of String, Map or List based on what methodResultType is set as.

I have created a MethodResultType class to account for methodResultType and it looks as follows

```
public enum MethodResultType {
    LIST,
    MAP,
    STRING;
    }
```

Now i know i have to write a class to account for methodResult and its variable nature based on methodResultType but cant think of a non botched up way to.

Any suggestions/ pointers in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
p1ng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List, Map and String have a common ancestor class: `java.lang.Object`. `methodResult` can thus be an Object.

You could also wrap the result and its type into a `MethodResult` object, that would provide methods such as `getType()`, `getValueAsString()`, `getValueAsList()` and `getValueAsMap()`. These last three methods would throw an IllegalStateException if the type of the value is not the type returned by the method.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. This makes sense. Im accepting this as an answer.